What are the convincing examples of copulas uncovering not obvious statistical dependences (or the lack of them)?
What may be a good, strong and convincing example demonstrating the power of copulas by uncovering some not obvious statistical dependencies?
I am especially interested in the example contrasting copula vs a simple calculation of a correlation coefficient for the original distributions.
Something like this - the (properly normalized) correlation coefficient of components of a bivariate distribution does not suggest a strong statistical dependence between them, but the copula distribution of these two components shows a clear dependence between them (possibly manifested in the value of a correlation coefficient calculated for the copula distribution?). Or the opposite - the correlation coefficient of the original bivariate distribution suggests strong dependence, but its copula shows that the statistical dependence is "weak", or just absent.
Mostly interested in an example described in terms of formulae (so that the samples could be generated, e.g. in MATLAB), but if somebody can point to the specific pre-generated bivariate distribution dataset (or its plots), that will work too.
Thank you!

Suppose we plot two variables, and suppose further their scatter plot shows a strong concave curve relationship. What do you think is the value of the correlation coefficient between these two variables? Also, what is copula dependency in this case?

@Maryam , thank you for the suggestion. If we forget about the "scatter", I can see that the bivariate data fitting a monotonic curve will result in its copula being a straight line. The Pearson correlation coefficient  from such original dependent data will generally be less than 1, but the P.c.c. from the copula will be exactly 1(?). I do not understand your requirement of concavity. In my example above, if the original data fits the concave, but not monotonic curve, the P.c.c. of the copula will be less than 1. Perhaps, you mean a different mechanism, than what my example illustrates?
